# Send POST request in Swift from JSON data sent over WebSocket

Tags: ios, json, swift, post

I am trying to send a POST request in `Swift` 2.2 based on a challenge that is sent over a WebSocket. My current code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/CK3tfAi2). In the `respondToChallenge` function, I need to execute the `JSON` sent via the `WebSocket`.

This is what a example challenge looks like:

```
[{
    "meth": "POST",
    "host": "https://openpokemap.pw"
    "cont": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    "user": "Firefox 42...."
    "data": "sjdbsjkbd" //Base64 encoded byte array
}]
```

And I also will need to POST the status code 200 over the "host" that is declared in the JSON.

Thanks, and go easy on me, this is my first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the JSON response, you can get the host returned pretty easily after serializing it.

```
do {
    let dict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(challenge.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)) as! [String: AnyObject]
    let host = response["host"] as? String
    print("Host: \(host)")
} catch {
    print("JSON error: \(error")
}
```

From there, you can use [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html) to make the POST request.

Comment: This returns nill.

Comment: Can you try now? I realized that challenge is actually a string, rather than a dictionary.

Comment: That worked, thanks. But at this point I already had a solution :D